# Як перекласти з російської "плюшка" в значенні перевага

Tags: переклад, from-russian, сленг, сталий-вираз

Російською можна сказати *щось має купу плюшок* маючи на увазі, що щось має купу плюсів, бонусів, переваг, додаткових можливостей тощо. Чи є якийсь відповідник українською? [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) відповіді не дає.

Answer (score 2):

- **фішка**

  Це не обов'язково перевага, це може бути просто якась специфіка, особливість тощо, але може вживатися й для позначення переваги. Я не знаю, чи не походить це переносне значення слова з російської, але де-факто вживається:

  > Там фішка в тому, що обладнання було їхнє, а сировина наша. <…> А в чому фішка твоєї роботи. <…> …вся фішка в тому, що ви бюджетники? //[Сергій Жадан, «Гімн демократичної молоді», с. 49, 90, 91](//books.google.com/books?id=IikYAQAAIAAJ&q=%D1%84%D1%96%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)
  >
  > Потрібна фішка, розумієте, забойна фішка. //[Марина Меднікова, «Тю!», с. 86](//books.google.com/books?id=FjgYAQAAIAAJ&q=%D1%84%D1%96%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)
  >
  > Інший Сергій (він не займається єдиноборствами, його фішка — теніс) грає роль арбітра. //[З журналу «Березіль»](//books.google.com/books?id=S6pOAQAAIAAJ&q=%D1%84%D1%96%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0).
- **козир**

  Зокрема [«Словники України он-лайн»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) наводять це слово як розмовний квазісинонім до слова *перевага*.
- **принада**

  Звідти ж. Це вже не розмовний варіант, а більш літературний. Також можна використовувати й значеннєвопов'язані дієслова, наприклад, «цей варіант *приваблює*/*притягає* тим, що… / багато чим».

Comment: А який зв'язкок між іменником **принада** та дієсловом **приваблювати**? Цей момент я не зовсім зрозумів.

Comment: @finesoul, суто моя особиста асоціація за значеннями [«3. Те, що вабить; спокуса. // Привабливі риси зовнішності. 4. Притягальна сила чого-небудь. 5. Краса, привабливість»](http://sum.in.ua/s/prynada); я не мав на увазі етимологічний/словотворчий зв'язок.

Answer (score 1):

Окрім розмовного варіанту "козир" можна також використати слово "[плюс](http://sum.in.ua/s/pljus)" (також розмовне):

род. а, перен., розм. **Позитивна сторона чогось; достоїнство кого-, чого-небудь.** — Кожна людина, яка навчилась грамоти, вже не та буде, що колись, темна й затуркана. Це вже плюс для суспільства (Василь Кучер, Трудна любов, 1960, 119);

//  **Взагалі що-небудь позитивне, бажане, очікуване.** Як то Ви себе почуваєте..? Що дала Вам Криворівня — плюс чи мінус? (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 440);

//  **Перевага, вигода.** На нашій стороні той плюс, що весь світ уже переходить тепер до такого руху, який повинен породити всесвітню соціалістичну революцію (Ленін, 45, 1974, 381).